# Can't add FULLTEXT index on MyISAM table

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I needed to add `FULLTEXT Searching` to my table and realized my table used `InnoDB` for its engine type. So I changed it

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

it worked fine. Now I try adding the fulltext index and get the error:

```
#1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes
```

My table *is* MyISAM, so why this error? I am running MySQL version 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.

Comment: Just to double check, if you run `SHOW TABLE STATUS` it shows MYISAM in the engine column.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Please run `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: Please show the `ALTER TABLE` command you used to add the FULLTEXT index.

Comment: my alter query: `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD FULLTEXT (
column_name)`, and my MySQL version: 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

Comment: I've added the answer on this old question in the answer space, as CW. May I trouble you to accept it, or create your own and accept that? If you do the latter, ping me and I'll delete my copy.

Answer (score 1):

Run these:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ENGINE=MyISAM;

ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD FULLTEXT (`column_name`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your default engine is InnoDB, so just use:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD FULLTEXT (`column_name`) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Hope this works :-)

Comment: your query isn't even correct, it gives syntax error. but read my edit to the question

Answer (score 0):

*(Added on behalf of the OP)*.

Here is the solution. I just came across this from the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-restrictions.html)

> Full-text searches are not supported for partitioned tables.

wouldn't it be easier if MySQL docs mentioned that in the first page of Fulltext Searching, as table partitioning is not unusual and many people would be using it for large tables? So, can't use `FULLTEXT` with partitioned tables.